# Pager fragments get blank on-click event

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

i have created the pager fragment programatically ,i can see the views of both fragment on swipe but issue is when i perform on-click event in any of fragment then my second fragment get blank [view of fragment on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUQRS.png) AND [fragment view after onclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNgeR.png)

```
activity code





    public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {           
                       InkPageIndicator indicator;          
           ViewPagerAdapter adapter;            
         Handler handler;              
       Timer timer;               
      Runnable runnable;              
       FragmentManager frgManager;             
        FragmentTransaction frgTransaction;         
            Fragment fragment;             
        private ContextMenuDialogFragment mMenuDialogFragment;           
          CoordinatorLayout main_content;           
          private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter;          
           ViewPager mViewPager;             
        private Toolbar toolbar;           
          private String catId;             
        private String mode;           
          private int matrix_count;            
         private int matrix_position;          
           private String sort;               
      private String productId;             
        private ArrayList<Products> productList = new ArrayList<Products>();                 private String table = "";             
        private NetworkCommunication net;             
        private int data = 10;                
     private String catalogueId = "",
     orderId = "";                
     private TextView mTitle;         
            private String product_id = "";              
       private int navigationBg, navigationfg, bottombarbg, bottombarfg;                 private String itemCode;                
     private HashMap<String, String> filterSendMap;          
           private String id = "";              
       private ArrayList<Cart.Product> cartProductList;           
          private ArrayList<Cart.Product> checkboxes;             
        private String cartId = "";                
     private String whichMaster = "";               
      private ArrayList<String> catalogue_keys;           
                                        @Override             
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
                         if (SingletonClass.getinstance() != null)             
            if 
    (SingletonClass.getinstance().screenshot.equalsIgnoreCase("not_allowed")) {                         
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);              
           }                     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);                         
             if (SingletonClass.getinstance() != null)            
                 defineColors();                 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {                         Window window = getWindow();                         
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);                
             window.setNavigationBarColor(navigationBg);           
                  window.setStatusBarColor(navigationBg);           
              }                     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);                     mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);           
              setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                     toolbar.setBackgroundColor(navigationBg);                 
        mTitle.setTextColor(navigationfg);                            
          Drawable back = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back);                                  // colors                             
         int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary);                     back.setColorFilter(navigationfg, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);                     toolbar.setNavigationIcon(back);                     
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
                   @Override                       
      public void onClick(View v) {              
                   onBackPressed();                
             }                  
       });                                           
        Intent intent = getIntent();              
           if (intent != null) {               
              mode = intent.getStringExtra("mode");                
             catId = intent.getStringExtra("cat_id");                         productId = intent.getStringExtra("product_id");            
     //            list = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");                         matrix_count = intent.getIntExtra("matrix_count", 0);             
                sort = intent.getStringExtra("sort");                         matrix_position = intent.getIntExtra("matrix_position", 0);                         catalogueId = intent.getStringExtra("catalogue_id");                         orderId = intent.getStringExtra("order_id");            
                 id = intent.getStringExtra("id");          
                   whichMaster = intent.getStringExtra("which_master");                         filterSendMap = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("filter_data");            
                 if (mode.equals("UpdateCart")) {           
                      product_id = intent.getStringExtra("product_id");
                                 cartId = intent.getStringExtra("id");             
                    cartProductList = 
    intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("product_list");           
                      checkboxes = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("checkboxes");                             catalogue_keys = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("catalogue_keys");           
                  }                             
             Log.d("In FullScreen Activity", "mode :: " + mode);             
                           }                           
          intent = new Intent(FullScreenActivity.this, MyService.class);                                  if (isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class, this)) {             
                stopService(intent);                         intent.putExtra("ScreenName", "Cart");                         intent.putExtra("ProductId", productId);                         intent.putExtra("Model", Build.MODEL);                         startService(intent);                     }
     else {                                  
        intent.putExtra("ScreenName", "Cart");                         intent.putExtra("ProductId", productId);                         intent.putExtra("Model", Build.MODEL);                         startService(intent);                   
      }                                                       
         mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);                                  net = new NetworkCommunication(this);            
             ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);                     cd.isConnectingToInternet();                
         if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {                 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                        
         public void run() {                            
         showAlertDialog(FullScreenActivity.this, "Internet Connection", "You dont have internet connection", true);                             }                         });               
          } else {            
                 table = "design_master"            
                      }                          
        @Override              
       public void onBackPressed() {                   
      Fragment selectedFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());            
             // based on the current position you can then cast the page to the correct                     // class and call the method:            
             FullScreenFragment ffragment = (FullScreenFragment) fragment;                     if (selectedFragment.equals(ffragment)
     && ffragment.hasExpandedSheet())
     {                      
       ffragment.collapseSheet();              
           } else {                 
            // handle by activity                  
           super.onBackPressed();             
            }                 }                                   
                                      public class FetchFullScreenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Products>> {            
             ArrayList<Products> list = null;               
          private ProgressDialog pdg;                        

              @Override                  
       protected void onPreExecute() {            
                 super.onPreExecute();                 
            pdg = ShowProgressDialog();                               
       }                               
       @Override                 
        protected ArrayList<Products> doInBackground(Void... params) {          
                   list = 
    net.fetchFullScreen(SingletonClass.getinstance().userId, productId, table, mode, catId, sort, "" + matrix_position, "" + data, catalogueId, orderId, filterSendMap, whichMaster);             //       
         currentPage = currentPage + 1;                      
                    return list;                     }                      

         @Override                
         public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Products> data) {                         Log.d("FetchFullScreenTask", "Running");                
             pdg.dismiss();                
             productList = data;                         //Log.wtf("!!!1", "listsize" + productList.size());                          //            if (productList.size() >= matrix_position) {                         Log.wtf("!!!1", "listsize" + productList.size());            
                 mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), productList, sort, matrix_position, catalogueId, catalogue_keys, whichMaster);                         mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);                         mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                         mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);                         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(matrix_position);             //     
           }               
          }              
       }                                       //pager adapter                           
       private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {                                  private String whichMaster = "";            
             private String sortmode, catalogueId;          
               private int page, myc_id;               
          private ArrayList<Products> productList;          
               private ArrayList<String> catalogue_keys;             
                         public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Products> productList, String sortMode,                                                   int page, String catalogueId, ArrayList<String> catalogue_keys, String whichMaster) {               
              super(fm);                    
         this.productList = productList;              
               this.catalogue_keys = catalogue_keys;                         this.sortmode = sortMode;                      
       this.page = page;                       
      this.catalogueId = catalogueId;            
                 this.whichMaster = whichMaster;         
                    Log.d("In Adapter", "page :: " + page);                         Log.d("In Adapter", "mode :: " + mode);              
               Log.d("In Adapter", "whichMaster :: " + whichMaster);                     }                                  @Override                     public Fragment getItem(int position) {                         // position = this.page;                         if (mode.equals("simple") || mode.equals("homescreen") || mode.equals("my_catalogue") ||                                 mode.equals("filter") || mode.equals("UpdateCart") || mode.equals("all") ||                                 mode.equals("catalogue_filter") || mode.equals("all_filter") ||                                 mode.equals("order_filter") || mode.equals("order") || mode.equals("all_past_orders") ||                                 mode.equals("all_past_orders_filter")) {                             frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();                             fragment = new FullScreenFragment(FullScreenActivity.this, mode, catId, productList, matrix_count, matrix_position, sort, catalogueId,                                     id, product_id, cartProductList, checkboxes, cartId, catalogue_keys, whichMaster);                             return fragment;                         } else {                             Log.d("In FullScreenActivity", "mode :: " + mode);                             return null;            
             }          
           }                            
      @Override                     public int getCount() {                         if (mode.equals("simple") || mode.equals("homescreen") || mode.equals("my_catalogue") ||                                 mode.equals("filter") || mode.equals("UpdateCart") || mode.equals("all") ||                
               mode.equals("catalogue_filter") || mode.equals("all_filter") ||                                 mode.equals("order_filter") || mode.equals("order") || mode.equals("all_past_orders") ||                                 mode.equals("all_past_orders_filter")) {             //                return matrix_count;             //            } else if (mode.equals("homescreen") || mode.equals("UpdateCart")) {           
                  return 1;          
   //            } else if (mode.equals("filter")) {        
     //                return productList.size();         
                } else {        
                     return -1;         
                }                  
   }                            
  }                         
                  @Override        
         protected void onDestroy() {       
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub                     super.onStop();                  
   stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));         
                     }                                     
      @NonNull                
 private ProgressDialog ShowProgressDialog() {               
      int navigationBg = Color.rgb(parseInt((SingletonClass.getinstance().fetchNavBgColor())[0].trim()),               
                  parseInt((SingletonClass.getinstance().fetchNavBgColor())[1].trim()),                             parseInt((SingletonClass.getinstance().fetchNavBgColor())[2].trim()));                   DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();                     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);                     int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;               
      int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;                                  final ProgressDialog pdg = new ProgressDialog(this);                     pdg.setMessage("please wait...");                     pdg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);                     pdg.show();                  
   Window window = pdg.getWindow();           
          window.setLayout(width / 3, width / 3);                     window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));                     window.setContentView(R.layout.progress_loader);                                  ImageView imgLoader = (ImageView) window.findViewById(R.id.progress_loader);                     imgLoader.getDrawable().setColorFilter(navigationBg, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);             //        // load the animation             //        Animation animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_in_left);             //        imgLoader.startAnimation(animFadein);                     pdg.setCancelable(false);       
              return pdg;        
         }                            

  public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {          

           AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();                     alertDialog.setTitle(title);                     alertDialog.setMessage(message);                                  Drawable alert = context.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);                     alert.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);                     alertDialog.setIcon(alert);                                  alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {        
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                             dialog.dismiss();              
               System.exit(1);
                         }               
      });                   
  alertDialog.show();         
        }                          
             }
```

```
  CODE OF PAGER AND FRAGMENTS



     public class SubProductPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {                          
            public SubProductPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {               
              super(fm);               
              fragementList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();                
             if (product != null)                   
              Log.i("FullScreenFragment", "subProductCount = " + product.subProductCount);               
              else                     
            Log.i("FullScreenFragment", "Product = " + product);              
           }                            

          @Override                 public int getCount() {               
              if (product != null) {                 
                return product.subProductCount + 1;               
              } else {                  
                  return 0;                  
               //return 1;                  
           }                
         }                             

         @Override                
         public Fragment getItem(int position) {               

              Fragment fragment = null;                
             //  subProductCheckedList==null? ArrayList<boolean> subProductCheckedList.add(true) : subProductCheckedList;              
               if (product != null)                 
                if (position == 0) {                 
                    if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("UpdateCart"))                                              fragment = SubProductFragment.newInstance(product, position, cartProductList.get(position).product_id,                                         cartProductList.get(position).grossWt, cartProductList.get(position).netWt, cartProductList.get(position).karat,                                         cartProductList.get(position).diamond, cartProductList.get(position).sizee, cartProductList.get(position).piece,                                         cartProductList.get(position).quantity, cartProductList.get(position).remarks, cartProductList.get(position).tone,                                         cartProductList.get(position).certi, cartProductList.get(position).hallmark, subProductCheckedList);                             else                         
                fragment = SubProductFragment.newInstance(product, position, product_id, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);                    
             } else {                
                     if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("UpdateCart"))                                 fragment = SubProductFragment.newInstance(product.subProductList.get(position - 1), position, cartProductList.get(position).product_id,                                         cartProductList.get(position).grossWt, cartProductList.get(position).netWt, cartProductList.get(position).karat,                                         cartProductList.get(position).diamond, cartProductList.get(position).sizee, cartProductList.get(position).piece,                                         cartProductList.get(position).quantity, cartProductList.get(position).remarks, cartProductList.get(position).tone,                                         cartProductList.get(position).certi, cartProductList.get(position).hallmark, subProductCheckedList);                             else                            
             fragment = SubProductFragment.newInstance(product.subProductList.get(position - 1), position, product_id, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);                      
           }                  
           fragementList.add(fragment);                              
            return fragment;                 }                          
            @Override                 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {                     if (product != null) {                  
               if (position == 0) {                 
                    return product.category_name;                     
            } else {                         
            return product.subProductList.get(position - 1).category_name;                         }                  
           } else {               
                  return "";                
             }               
          }
                                  }


        public static class SubProductFragment extends Fragment {

        static SubProductFragment newInstance(Products product, int position, String product_id,                                                   String gross_wt, String net_wt, String karat, String diamond,                                                   String size, String piece, String quantityy, String remarks, String tone,                                                   String certification, String hallmark, ArrayList<Boolean> subProductCheckedList)

         {                
         SubProductFragment f = new SubProductFragment();              
           Bundle args = new Bundle();                
         args.putInt("page", position);               
          args.putParcelable("product", product);              
           if (mode.equals("UpdateCart")) {                
             args.putString("product_id", product_id);                     args.putString("gross_wt", gross_wt);                
             args.putString("net_wt", net_wt);               
              args.putString("karat", karat);               
              args.putString("diamond", diamond);
                             args.putString("size", size);                 
            args.putString("piece", piece);                 
            args.putString("tone", tone);                   
          args.putString("quantityy", quantityy);                     args.putString("remarks", remarks);                 
            args.putString("certi", certification);                     args.putString("hallmark", hallmark);                     args.putSerializable("productcheckedlist", subProductCheckedList);               
          }               
          f.setArguments(args);                            
          return f;        
 }


        @Override              
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {                 
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_details, container, false);
                     }                          

        @Override             public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {              
           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);                
         initialize(view, page);              
           try {                  
           setData(product, page);
                                      } catch (Exception e) 
        {                     e.printStackTrace();              
           }             
        }


        }
```

Logcat

```
06-06 11:17:33.373 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-06 11:17:47.060 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/PageIndicator: dot 1 fraction:   1.0
06-06 11:17:47.235 19842-19852/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.442ms
06-06 11:17:59.203 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@de18b72
06-06 11:17:59.204 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@db14bc3
06-06 11:17:59.286 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@aecd89c
06-06 11:17:59.286 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@57ff2a5
06-06 11:18:02.673 19842-19976/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7f77452400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f98048540
06-06 11:18:08.072 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/PageIndicator: dot 1 fraction:   1.0
06-06 11:18:29.072 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/PageIndicator: dot 1 fraction:   1.0
06-06 11:18:50.702 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/PageIndicator: dot 1 fraction:   1.0
06-06 11:19:02.727 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/FA: Activity paused, time: 218137259
06-06 11:19:03.733 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/FA: Application backgrounded. Logging engagement
06-06 11:19:03.761 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:1 and remote module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:9
06-06 11:19:03.761 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.tagmanager, version >= 9
06-06 11:19:03.829 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz W/GoogleTagManager: No container asset found in /assets/containers. Checking top level /assets directory for container assets.
06-06 11:19:03.840 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
06-06 11:19:03.840 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 26ms
06-06 11:19:03.851 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=102992}]
06-06 11:19:03.852 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/FA: Using measurement service
06-06 11:19:03.852 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/FA: Connecting to remote service
06-06 11:19:03.862 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/FA: Connected to remote service
06-06 11:19:03.863 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
06-06 11:19:08.871 19842-22602/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
06-06 11:19:11.717 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/PageIndicator: dot 1 fraction:   1.0
06-06 11:19:32.716 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/PageIndicator: dot 1 fraction:   1.0
06-06 11:19:53.719 19842-19842/com.triologic.jewelflowpro.vivaaz D/PageIndicator: dot 1 fraction:   1.0
```

Comment: post ur activity in which view pager is present

Comment: @AvinashRoy you can see just added the code

Comment: post the activity too

Comment: @AvinashRoy activity code added